# @db.Decimal in Prisma ("s", "e", "d")

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, decimal, prisma

Why when i write in schema.prisma:

```
value            Decimal?             @db.Decimal(7, 4)
```

When i take value from db I always have:

```
"value": {
      "s": 1,
      "e": 0,
      "d": [
        1
      ]
```

where "d" is my real value.

I don't want to have "s" and "e". I just want to have "value": 1

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please try to properly format your question so it's easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use `Float` instead (which actually uses double precision in most providers). If you need more precision you should learn how to use Decimal.js which is what Prisma uses to process decimals like you are currently using. I'm not sure how it works, but I'd imagine that `s` and `e` (sign and exponent?) are important and should not be ignored.